# Get all users from text channel

Tags: c#, .net, discord, bots, dsharp+

I wanna get list of all users in text channel by channel id. I tried this with that code:

```
var channel = ctx.Guild.GetChannel(id);

var users = channel.Users;

foreach (var item in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

(id = channel-id)

but instead of list of all users, i got only two users: me and bot.

i was try to found answer but there are only not working solutions e.g. enable permissions in the bot settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable these privileged Gateway Intents at https://discord.com/developers , where you want to navigate to your Project and then your bot. A few scrolls below the token reveal button you can find these options:
[image]